# NDSolve for complex variables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex, physics

I am trying to simulate a multiple pendulum system with damping as follows:

```
l = 0.6 (1 + 0.00 I); g = 9.8;
x0 = 0.01;
coord[n_] := Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, n}];
vel[n_] := D[coord[n], t];
mass[1] = {x0 Cos[\[Omega] t], 0};
mass[i_] := 
  mass[i - 1] + {l Sin[Subscript[x, i - 1][t]], -l Cos[
      Subscript[x, i - 1][t]]};
ke[i_] := With[{v = D[mass[i + 1], t]}, v.v/2];
pe[i_] := g mass[i + 1][[2]];
L[n_] := Sum[ke[i] - pe[i], {i, n}];
eq[n_] := 
  Table[D[D[L[n], vel[n][[m]]], t] - D[L[n], coord[n][[m]]] == 0, {m, 
    n}];
ic[n_] := 
  Table[{Subscript[x, i][0] == 0, Subscript[x, i]'[0] == 0}, {i, n}] //
    Flatten;
```

So that eq[n] is the Lagrangian equation of motion for n linked pendula. Now I can get a solution with

```
SOL[n_] := 
 NDSolve[{FullSimplify[eq[n]] /. \[Omega] -> 1, ic[n]} // Flatten, 
  Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, n}], {t, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

(try for instance `f=SOL[4]`). However if I add a little bit of damping by changing `l=0.6(1+0.01I)`, the solver fails with the error

```
NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. >>
```

So my question is whether there is some method available to NDSolve that I can call to make this work for complex variables.

Comment: Your code works fine in V10.4.1.  What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: The solutions I get are real-valued, not complex.

Comment: yes it works as is, but replace the first line with `l=0.6(1+0.01I)` to make l complex. currently trying your solution with that replacement, it's taking a while.

Comment: Try the `Solve` step with a symbolic `l` (`Clear[l]`).  Then substitute `l -> 0.6(1+0.01I)`.  The approximate real numbers are bogging `Solve` down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you solve for the second derivatives, you won't have to use `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` and things will work ok.

Solving for the second derivatives be faster if you start with exact coefficients. Also, if you clear `l`, solve for the derivatives, and then substitute a value for `l`, `Solve` won't choke on the algebra.  The long time it takes is probably why `NDSolve` advises the use of the option:

> NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}. >>

```
(*l = 0.6 (1 + 0.00 I) // Rationalize;*)  (* old solution *)
Clear[l];
g = 9.8 // Rationalize;
x0 = 0.01 // Rationalize;
(*... rest of OP's code...*)

(* This replaces eq[] in NDSolve; saves the result for ease of reuse *)
Clear[neweq];
neweq[n_, ω0_] := neweq[n, ω0] = 
  Equal @@@ First@ Simplify@
     Solve[eq[n] /. ω -> ω0, Table[Subscript[x, i]''[t], {i, n}]]

(* Here is where we substitute the value for l *)
Clear[SOL];
SOL[n_] := NDSolve[{neweq[n, 1] /. l -> 0.6 (1 + 0.01 I), ic[n]},
  Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, n}], {t, 0, 100}]

mysol = First@SOL[4]
```

Since the solutions are complex, one has to decide what to plot.  I chose the magnitude.  The plots nearly overlap, so I offset them:

```
Plot[
 0.01 Range[n] + Table[Abs@ Subscript[x, i][t], {i, n}] /. mysol // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, that did it, although depending on the value of ω i use, i get numerical errors. for this example i used ω=1, but for 100 i get `Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>`